# JSF 2.0 "Conversion Error setting value 'courseID' for 'null Converter' on Primefaces Picklist

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am getting the following error when I want to save the data of my picklist

> 'Group [id=null, groupName=TEST,
>   distinguishedName="distinguishedNameForGroup"' für 'null Converter'.

This is the converter I use for it
@FacesConverter(value="groupConverter", forClass=Group.class)
public class GroupConverter implements Converter{

```
@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
        String value) {
     if (value.trim().equals("")) {
            return null;
     }

    Object ret = null;
    if (component instanceof PickList) {

        Object dualList = ((PickList) component).getValue();
        DualListModel<?> dl = (DualListModel<?>) dualList;
        for (Object o : dl.getSource()) {
            String id = ((Group) o).getDistinguishedName();

            if (value.equalsIgnoreCase(id)) {
                ret = o;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (ret == null)
            for (Object o : dl.getTarget()) {
                String id = ((Group) o).getDistinguishedName();
                if (value.equals(id)) {
                    ret = o;
                    break;
                }
            }
    }
    return ret;
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
        Object value) {
    if (value == null || value.equals("")) {
        return "";
    } else {
        String str = "";
        if (value instanceof Group) {
            str = ""
                    + ((Group) value)
                            .getDistinguishedName();
        }
        return str;
    }

}
```

}

And the code for the pickList:

```
<p:pickList
    value="#{bean.groups}" var="group"
    itemLabel="#{group.groupName}" itemValue="#{group}"
    converter="groupConverter">
</p:pickList>
```

I don't understand the error, because in the web I found that the converter is not called, but definitely is. I am running out of ideas. There is no null value or anything. The Group.class have an equal and hashcode method.

**Update:**
I found out that the selectOneMenu makes the error. This is the code for it. There is no converter, that might be the problem. Testing it.

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="abteilungsleiterrolle"
    value="#{bean.object.group}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.source}" var="q"
        itemValue="#{q}" itemLabel="#{q.groupName}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 @ViewScope   
@FacesConverter(value="pickListConverter")    
public class PickListConverter implements Converter{   
    Map<String, Object> tmp;
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        tmp = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    }
    @Override   
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        return tmp.get(value);
    }

    @Override   
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {  
        if (value == null || value.equals("")) {
            return "";
        } else {
            tmp.put(value.toString(), value);
            return value.toString();
        }
    }   
}
```

Whit this converter only make sure that your **toString()** (*NameClass and fields and id*) for example *"Group[id=" + id +"]"* are well format but this converter works for any **class**

And remember change converter name:

```
<p:pickList
value="#{bean.groups}" var="group"
itemLabel="#{group.groupName}" itemValue="#{group}"
converter="pickListConverter">
```

Comment: Try with this changes

Comment: Can do you debug method `getAsObject` and say me what gives you `value` and can see if map get this???

Comment: getAsObject is not called. However getAsString is?!

Comment: `getAsString` is used when xhtml are been constructed and `getAsObject` when you submit xhtml

Comment: Tried it now with an ApplicationScope as Oskars Pakers said, now it's called. value is the toString(); method of the object and the map returns me the object

Comment: Then works? if this yes, remember you can use for any Object. Enjoy yourself.

Comment: But if you say me that with `ApplicationScope` map return object no?

Comment: It is working, the failure is the selectOneMenu I have on the page :/ Sorry, thanks for the help.

Comment: You can use this for converter of `selectOneMenu ` too

Comment: Yeah but I think I can't use with `@ApplicationScope` as the map never get's empty then ;)

Comment: Yo can try `@SessionScope`

Answer (score 0):

Part of error message " `für 'null Converter'.`" indicates that there is no valid converter found.
You can try folowing:

- If #{bean.groups} resolves to object `List<Group>` JSF should find matching converter by class as you have specified `forClass=Group.class`, but i think you don`t have to give your converter a name
- Try to remove for class attribute to reference it by name
- You can annotate it with `@ManagedBean` and specify el for bean e.g. `#{groupConverter}`

If converter method is called, but error still persists, then converter not found ("null Converter") error can be produced by other jsf component. Keep in mind that if you specify value="#{bean.group}" where bean.group is Group.class object and omit converter, then JSF will lookup for converter annotated with forClass="Group.class". Here if you made converter as bean you have to specify converter for each component.

Comment: As I mentioned the converter is found. I tried your solutions anyway.
If I use forClass only I get a NullPointerException. And I used @Named instead of '@ManagedBean' as I am using CDI. However, it's the same converter error.

Comment: No, converter is not found :) it finds "null Converter". After each change you might need to recompile/rebuild the project. If you are developing in development mode e.g. using Netbeans then jsf somehow does not find new converter.

Comment: But the values are converted in Strings and the methods are called

Comment: Values are converted to strings by resolving expression #{group.groupName}, that does not prove your converters existance.

Comment: #{group.groupName} are the values who are displayed, but I mean in the HTML Code there is the converted text. And made some test logs in the methods. They are definitely called.

Comment: I don`t know what you refer as "converted text" but your converter is not found, that`s for sure :) Try to remove @FacesConverter annotation at all and annotate only with @Named and @ApplicationScoped (if you use CDI beans) or @ManagedBean and @ApplicationScoped (if you use JSF beans) and then specify converter="#{groupConverter}". DOn`t forget to clean and redeploy

Comment: Made it `@ApplicationScoped` and `@Named`, I used it with the code of @Mathew Rock and made a System.out.println(); in the `getAsObject()` method. And it gets printed. So it is called.

Comment: But if you still get the error then maybe converter is not found by other component? Can you paste the whole jsf page?

Comment: That's actually the failure. I just removed the picklist and the error still occurs. My selectOneMenu makes the error...